# Calculate Route keeps ploting not the shortest route

Tags: here-api

I'm using HERE's **calculate route** API to present routes on the map. In a few places, I keep getting results that led me here as I am seemingly unable to achieve reasonable results. Near Warsaw, my route keeps turning to the north towards the city just to turn south-west that is back in the main direction whereas there is a straight road that would allow achieving the same. My users expect routes to be as straight as possible and I am not able to defend nor explain such deviations as this in route plotting.

Request parameteres:

```
url: 'https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json',
  method: 'get',
  params:
   { app_id: 'is-it-possible-to-learn-this-power-?',
     app_code: 'not-from-a-jedi',
     mode:
      'fastest;truck;traffic:disabled;tollroad:0,motorway:0,boatFerry:0,tunnel:0,dirtRoad:0,park:0',
     waypoint0: '54.11025,22.96542',
     waypoint1: '49.19168,16.65446',
     waypoint2: '49.59958,17.26838',
     avoidSeasonalClosures: true,
     language: 'pl-pl',
     excludeCountries: 'CHE,DEU',
     metricSystem: 'metric',
     legAttributes: 'length,travelTime',
     jsonAttributes: 9,
     routeAttributes: 'shape,legs',
     limitedWeight: 40 }
}
```

It is worth noting that at first I was convinced that I get this result because of the traffic settings, but it turn out no matter which option (concerning traffic) do I choose I always end up with what it look like the same route shape.

Result on map:
[image]

Result near the city:
[image]

**My question is**: is there a way to achieve a straight route without detours such as this in my example or maybe this is totally acceptable route but I am unaware of the reason?

Comment: Does it change if you modify some of your parameters, e.g. limitedWeight?

Comment: Of course but this is not a solution. _LimitedWeight_ means different road restrictions which will result in route trace that violates road restrictions if my customers will send shipping truck to which different (higher) weight limit applies.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this problem was to *soft exlude* motorways and to *avoidSeasonalClosures* as there are some near Warsaw and Wroclaw.

Now request params look like this:

```
{ app_id: 'i-am-the-senate',
app_code: 'not-yet',
mode: 'fastest;truck;motorway:-2',
waypoint0: '54.11025,22.96542',
waypoint1: '49.19168,16.65446',
waypoint2: '49.59958,17.26838',
avoidSeasonalClosures: true,
avoidAreas: '53.204942,23.05379;53.100605,23.254131',
excludeCountries: 'CHE,DEU',
legAttributes: 'length,travelTime',
jsonAttributes: 9,
routeAttributes: 'shape,legs',
limitedWeight: 40 }
```

The excluded area is the road near and north to the city of Bialystok as this road is not optimal.

[image]